# Protractor e2e - drag and drop text

Tags: text, textbox, drag-and-drop, protractor

It seems I can drag and drop DOM elements using `browser.actions()` sequence:

```
browser.
actions().
mouseMove(elem1).
mouseDown().
mouseMove(elem2).
mouseUp().
perform();
```

I would like to select some text within a paragraph, then drag and drop it into search-box. It could be entire text content of some DOM element if it makes things simpler, but not the DOM element itself (my search-box handle DOM elements in different way).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of what needs to be automated? Thanks.

Comment: This is the simplest code I could think of: `<div id="target"></div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>`.

I want to select "Lorem ipsum" (just the text not the node `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>` and later drag&drop it onto the drop zone `#target`. 

**`#target` accepts text only.** It is meant to accept text dragged by user form the same window, another window or external text sources like MS Notepad.

I was looking for a shortcut like just dropping text from test source (without select and drag steps) but I didn't succeed.